# SQL: finding similar rows to other same table in special column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using SQLITE for running this query:

```
SELECT * FROM phrases1, phrases2 WHERE phrases1.word LIKE ('%' +phrases2.word+ '%')
```

but not works. 
two tables phrases1, phrases2 are same and have column name word and I want to filter the first table by rows that word column is similar to the word column of second table .  while this works:

```
SELECT * FROM phrases1, phrases2 WHERE phrases1.word LIKE phrases2.word
```

but I want to use wildcards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQLite operator for string concatenation is `||` not `+`:

```
SELECT * FROM phrases1, phrases2
WHERE phrases1.word LIKE '%' || phrases2.word || '%'
```

Also I don't know what the effect of having parentheses around your `LIKE` expression would be, but you don't need them there.  But you should really write your query using explicit joins, better yet use aliases too:

```
SELECT *
FROM phrases1 p1
INNER JOIN phrases2 p2
    ON p1.word LIKE '%' || p2.word || '%'
```

Comment: Reload the page...I botched my first answer.